# Get Token from destination response and pass to new Channel in Mirth

Tags: web-services, rest, authentication, mirth

I've created a channel in **Mirth** which first calls authentication service and returns response. Source I've configured to **HTTP Listener** and in destination I've used **HTTP Sender** which calls a rest service for login and returns token as below.

{"token":"5912aa99-af21-5614-c232-d22be9e5c102","app":"TEST API Suite","expires":845,"userID":"ZCT06D123Cfk20oROB9x-bEXeY12oQGfack6dMMc-0o="}

Question: From the response that I'm receiving from rest service , how do I extract the token part and then pass that token to another channel and use it for calling another service.

Is there a way that I can set the token in a variable or global map in Destination1 and use that in Destination2 configuration?

Please Help. I'm a Newbie in Mirth.
Thanks.

Comment: You've got the answer on Mirth forum. Why to double post then?

Comment: I didn't know posting same question in different forums on the same day and time just because you are expecting an urgent response could be an issue.

Comment: Well, then answer to your own question showing what exactly worked in your particular case. That may be useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

The following helped me and solved my issue.
Add a post processor script as this in **channel1**:

```
var dest1 = responseMap.get("Destination 1");
var response123=dest1.getMessage();
var obj = JSON.parse(response123);
logger.info('token==='+obj.token);
router.routeMessage('newChannelName', obj.token);
return;
```

And then in **newChannelName** Channel preprocessor script, I was able to get this token as message.

```
logger.info('token: '+message);
```